# Windows 8.1: Delayed PIN or picture logon after booting

Tags: windows-8.1, login, delay, pin

When ever i turn ON my Windows 8.1 laptop, I can instantly login with my password, as I would expect.

However, if I use my PIN instead, the system mostly freezes for about one minute: The input box disappears, the "back"-Button becomes unresponsive. After one minute, the login is executed as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit of a known issue with Windows 8.1 sadly, however there is a work around that has worked for some people.

Start Menu > Type 'services' > launch the services list > find 'Credential Manager (AKA VaultSVC) > Double Click or Right Click Properties > Change Start Up Type from Manual to Automatic > Apply > Test Again.

Let me know how you get on...

Comment: I just tried your answer...but the problem still exists :(

Comment: Yeah it's a strange one as that worked for about 50% of people in my office and didn't for the other 50%... Unfortunately for them its company policy to use PIN so all I can recommend for you is to get rid of PIN and go back to password it will be quicker...

Comment: then do you have any other solution ?

Comment: As far as I'm aware its a bug with Microsoft and no other solution is available. If I manage to make any progress on the problem in my office I'll update you with my findings :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case login delay was caused by broken NvStreamService, after disabling it I got normal boot time.
Also you can try Windows Performance Recorder/Analyzer from [Windows ADK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=39982) to find out what caused this issue.